# Aligned underbraces between amsmath equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, amsmath, math-operators

I have an `\amsmath` `aligned` environment containing some equations aligned with `&=`. I want to be able to place underbraces between the equations in such a way that that both the contents and “point” of the brace can be easily specified, with the rest of the equation aligned/shifted accordingly. The spacing between the brace and the equations should be uniform. Here's a mockup of what I'd like:[image: brace between lines].

I need to be able to stack an arbitrary number of such equations/braces. The next line would be  an `&= 3` with an underbrace indicating that the 1+2 was reduced to the 3.
Basic code for the equations with no braces is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $\begin{aligned}
    1 + 1 + 1 &= 1 + 1 + 1 \\
              &= 1 + 2
  \end{aligned}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternative view on the grouping, which might be of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\begin{document}
\[
  %\setlength{\jot}{.5\jot} Adjust to bring the equations closer vertically
  \begin{aligned}
    1 + 1 + 1 &= 1 + \underbrace{1 + 1} \\
              &= \mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{1+\hspace{1.9em}}}}1 + \makebox[\widthof{$1+1$}]{$2$} \\
              &= \makebox[\widthof{$1+\hspace{1.9em}$}]{3}
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

The line-spacing within `align`-and-friends are defined in terms of `\jot`. So, you could consider adjusting it to suit your needs.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to determine the value for the `\hspace` apart from trial and error?

Comment: @Texman: Yes. You can place stuff in boxes, measure them and then use that to determine the exact width of the boxes. It's a lot of work for very little reward, since you may have to measure numerous boxes for a single entry. If the structure is predictable, then one can wrap it in a macro. Something that might be arbitrary in nature could be difficult to automate via a macro.

Answer (score 3):

As long as we add not too many one-cipher numbers, we can use the effect, that all ciphers have the same width. It gives a little bit more general solution, then the one of the predecessor.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r@{{}={}}c}
   1 + 1 + 1 +1& 1 + 1+ \underbrace{1 + 1} \\
              &1+\underbrace{1 + 2}\\
       &\underbrace{1+3}\\
      &4
\end{array}
\]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are always grouping things on the right, you can make this work by making the right-hand side right-aligned (using an `alignat` environment), and then adding an appropriate amount of space on the right to get the alignment under the brace. This technique also works equally well for grouping on the left.

[image: Equations with progressive grouping]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}\noindent
Grouping on the right:
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  6! 
  &={} & 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times \underbrace{2 \times 1}
  \\&={} & 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times \underbrace{3 \times 2}      \mspace{16mu}
  \\&={} & 6 \times 5 \times \underbrace{4 \times 6}               \mspace{32mu}
  \\&={} & 6 \times \underbrace{5 \times 24}                       \mspace{44mu}
  \\&={} & \underbrace{6 \times 120}                               \mspace{56mu}
  \\&={} & 720                                                     \mspace{72mu}
\end{alignat*}
Grouping on the left:
\begin{align*}
  6!
  &=                 \underbrace{6 \times 5} \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1
  \\&= \mspace{10mu} \underbrace{30 \times 4} \times 3 \times 2 \times 1
  \\&= \mspace{20mu} \underbrace{120 \times 3} \times 2 \times 1
  \\&= \mspace{35mu} \underbrace{360 \times 2} \times 1
  \\&= \mspace{50mu} \underbrace{720 \times 1}
  \\&= \mspace{65mu} 720
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array instead of aligned if this this what you require:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}  
    \usepackage{amsmath}  

\begin{document}  
  $$\begin{array}{rcc}  
    1 + 1 + 1 &= &1 + 1 + 1 \\  
              &= &\underbrace{1 + 2}\\  
              &=&3  
    \end{array}$$  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The spacing will not quite be right, but worse still, it doesn't allow the OP to underbrace and align only a part of the expression as described in the question.

Comment: Number of columns could always be increased here as necessary to get the exact output.

Comment: This doesn't really work in general if the things being grouped don't happen to have the right length for alignment to happen by accident.